# Create a dynamic RelativeLayout to add existing data on new rows through an adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I know that I cannot create a ListView inside of a scroll view due to Android issues. Although there is a hack available for that, I am not sure if that will be compatible with older Android SDK's or not. So want to do a different layout.

```
<RelativeLayout ID=R1>
<TextView ID=A1 layout_weight=0.5>
<ImageView ID=A2 layout_weight=0.5>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Database: String array textView values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and ImageView values: A, B, C, D, E.

Now, I want to add the database values dynamically in the RelativeLayout

```
- Calculate the max number of values available to add in TextView and ImageView
- Start a for loop and read data from the array
- Add data from the array creating a new row for every (TextView, ImageView)
```

Can someone pls help me with creating this adapter? I have tried modifying my listView adapter but somehow it doesn't work for RelativeLayout as the param setAdapter is not available for RelativeLayout. Also, moving forward I want to connect this data through an excel-sheet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

may be this will helpful

```
void init() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findById(.......);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (Worker worker : workers) {
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setText(worker.toString());
        button.setId(5);
        linearLayout.addView(button);
    }
}
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

</LinearLayout>
```